# Why (or how) does a Keras model skip Stemming or Lemmatization steps?

Tags: keras, nlp, sentiment-analysis

This [Keras article / tutorial here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification) does perform text standardization i.e removing HTML elements, punctuation, etc. from the text dataset, however, there is a distinct lack of any stemming or lemmatization before the vectorization step.

I have a bit of experience in deep learning but I am very new to NLP, and I just got to know (from a [different tutorial on Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/course/machinelearning/learn/lecture/19958908#overview), which BTW was using Bag of Words) that using either a Stemmer or a Lemmatizer helps in bringing down the vocabulary size and hence increases performance. I am a bit baffled by the absence of this step in the Keras-way of doing things.

Here is one assumption of mine - is it omitted because a Neural Network model is capable of handling a larger vocabulary size? I cannot think of any other reason(s) as to why that might be the case.

Answer (score 0):

No. Simply not supported. You have to resort to tools such as NLTK for the stemming or lemmatization.

I cannot speak for Keras or TensorFlow but this is an understandable design: You cannot do stemming or lemmatization without knowledge to the language. The rules are not generally portable from one language to another. Hence it is better to leave it to the specific NLP library rather than include it in the generic deep learning library such as TensorFlow.

Comment: This has been asked before with an in depth response.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56556837/does-keras-tokenizer-perform-the-task-of-lemmatization-and-stemming